# Having trouble declaring a reference to generic classes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a generic class with the following signature

`class Picker<U: Multipickable>`

In another class, I'd like to create a `delegate` property of type `Picker` described above. I want to pass information back to `Picker` as a result of some action from this other class.

```
//in another class
weak var delegate: Picker! //error
```

There's 2 compiler errors stating the following:

Reference to generic type `Picker` requires arguments in <...>

and

`weak` cannot be applied to non-class type `<<error type>>`

Are there any ways around this?

Answer (score 0):

The first error say the `Picker` require arguments in <...>. So, you must put the class type which is defined in Picker to <...>

```
var delegate: Picker<Multipickable>!
```

The second error is thrown because the first error, when your `Picker` class use in wrong way, it become an `<<error type>>`, so you cannot `weak` it